# Replace Ninject code with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

I have found this post [Replace Ninject with Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658786/replace-ninject-with-simple-injector)

but havent found the solution for following migrations.
With Ninject:

```
public class ServiceClass : IServiceClass
...
IKernel kernel
...
this.kernel.Bind<IServiceClass>().ToMethod(context => this);
```

I try to use this construction with Simple Injector:

```
public class ServiceClass : IServiceClass
   ...
   Container container
   ...
   this.container = container;
   this.container.Register<IServiceClass>(() => container.GetInstance<ServiceClass >());
```

is it equal to Ninject one?

The second part in Ninject is:

```
public void BindSomeCallback(DelegateNumberOne delegateNumberOne)
{        
   this.kernel.Rebind<DelegateNumberOne>().ToConstant(delegateNumberOne);
}
```

to:

```
public void BindSomeCallback(DelegateNumberOne delegateNumberOne)
{ 
   this.container.Register<DelegateNumberOne, delegateNumberOne>();
}
```

Comment: Why are putting the registration of `ServiceClass` in that class itself, instead of placing all registrations inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)?

Comment: @Steven this ServiceClass is kind of entry point - and has 2 Constructors - one to work with Test Suits - dependecies prepared for tests and other one working code

Comment: @Steven Delphi part of legacy code start  the .NET part I have shown here

Comment: I would strongly consider you to *not* scatter your DI registration throughout your entire code base and prevent letting your application take a dependency on your container. Place all registrations in a single place (your Composition Root).

Comment: @Steven The ServiceClass - it is a single place

Comment: This single place where all registrations are made? But why do you register that class itself?

Comment: @Steven Thanks for you response - I have upvoted and accepted it - I answer you comment "why do you register that class itself?" a bit later =)

Comment: @Steven - are you the only Simple Injector developer? - I mean not who use it, but who develop it as a tool

Comment: [This](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/team/view) is the team.

Comment: @Steven not a very large one =(

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunate, but true. But I believe that holds for all IoC containers. Most of the work is usually done by one developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it equal to Ninject one?

Nope. This is:

```
this.container.Register<IServiceClass>(() => this);
```

But since you're actually registering a singleton, you can better write it as follows:

```
this.container.RegisterSingle<IServiceClass>(this);
```

> The second part in Ninject is:

Again here, you want to register a delegate as singleton:

```
this.container.RegisterSingle<DelegateNumberOne>(delegateNumberOne);
```